# Photodiode in forward circuit

Tags: photodiode

I have a BPV10 photodiode. It works fine in reverse bias and conducting mode. For curiosity, I wanted to check its behavior in forward bias, so I calculated the series resistor for having a current of about 40mA.((5-1)/.04)=100 ohm)

I tested on the breadboard but I got confused, because all the time the voltage across the photodiode was 5V instead of 1 volt. That means the photodiode doesn't work right and the current is zero (Vresistor=0.) I tested more than one photodiode and even changed the pin's orientation but the same results were seen.

My circuit on the breadboard:

[image]

[image]

The voltage across the power supply and the photodiode is the same(5V)

I would be grateful if you could help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: How did you test on breadboard ...

Comment: Yes, a photo would be useful. We've had a few erroneous / face-palm breadboard questions recently.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, tomorrow I will send you the picture of my circuit at the lab.

Comment: What were you hoping to achieve by forward biasing the photodiode?

Comment: I just want to verify that its behavior is as the same as a normal diode.

Comment: I have uploaded the pictures. I have bought some new photodiodes too but the same results appear. Your can check by yourself.

Comment: @JohnJin from your picture, you are measuring across the voltage supply. You have to measure across the diode.

Comment: Yes, I just want to say that the voltage of the power supply is 5 volts and (I missed the picture of the ) measured voltage of the photodiode (cathode to anode voltage) is 5 volts instead of 1 volts.

Comment: I tested for another photodiode at the market which the part number is unknown. the results are the same.